# DVD Flick and Audio Problems?

Tags: windows-vista, audio, dvd, burning

Now when I burn DVD's with DVD Flick then audio seems to be a little off like a Godzilla flick for example. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this happening when the disc is played back through a standalone DVD player (not software)?

Comment: I am having this issue too

Answer (score 5):

There are many reports about DVD Flick getting the video/audio out of sync, which is why several sources recommend paying for a commercial product. The name of [ConvertXtoDVD](http://www.vso-software.fr/products/convert_x_to_dvd/) comes up consistently in this connection.

From this thread : [Audio Problems Using Dvd Flick](http://ipb.quicksilverscreen.com/index.php?showtopic=146237)

> I also had a sync problem happen after
>   many successful conversions. Try this
>   if you have one of your problem
>   conversion saved as a project.
>   Open the out-of-sync project. Then go
>   the Edit Title (u see this choice on
>   the right side) In the next window
>   that opens, select Audio Tracks.
>   Then select again from the right side,
>   Edit.
>
> It is here I discovered a
>   "millisecond" delay" entry. One time I
>   found an 80,000 millisecond audio
>   delay (if memory serves me).
>  You
>   will find here an option to "**Ignore Audio delay for this track**." I
>   "**ticked**" this option and re-did the
>   conversion and **it was OK**.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you use to play back or if your program has audio syncing options.  I would try and figure out why it changed now so you don't have to mess with syncing it later using something like ffdshow as it is very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Is the error on the disc or on the computer playing it back?  Try playing the disc in more than one place.  If you get the same results on your computer and your dvd player, then you should consider getting different DVD burning software.  If the error is only on the computer and not the DVD player, try a different piece of playback software.