# Free Tool to let you burn an mp4 to a DVD that can be watched in a DVD player

Tags: video, dvd, mp4

I am looking for a tool that will let me take an mp4 and burn it as a DVD (you know, the kind I can watch in my DVD player).

I tried [DVD Flick](http://www.dvdflick.net/index.php) but when the DVD was done the audio was off by at least a full second.

I saw this question: [Burning a mpg file(audio+video) to DVD to view in a DVD player](https://superuser.com/questions/89467/burning-a-mpg-fileaudiovideo-to-dvd-to-view-in-a-dvd-player)  But the tool mentioned there does not say it supports MP4s.

Any one have any cool tools for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using DVD Flick.

This question helped me fix the audio issue: [DVD Flick and Audio Problems?](https://superuser.com/questions/38812/dvd-flick-and-audio-problems)

Answer (score 1):

VisualHub does this perfectly (and not just from MP4), just as long as your source video does not use AC3 audio. It's been discontinued, but is still floating around. One of its reincarnations, FilmRedux, isn't fully baked yet. Another reincarnation, VideoMonkey, hasn't implemented non-MP4 output (such as DVD) yet.

Stomp might do it too.